# The easiest way to include javascript code to wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, javascript

I built a website widget. If customers want to add it to their site, they need to put a small snippet of javascript code to head or any part of html, similar as you insert google analytics code.

What would be the easiest way to describe my customers how to do that if they are not programmers? Magento has option to add Miscellaneous Scripts into head through admin. Is there anything like that possible also with wordpress site?

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because answers would attract opionated answers since there is many ways this can be done and the ease of them will vary from person to person.

Comment: My opinionated answer would be scripts can be added via WP widgets, functions.php, footer.php, header.php, plugins, Google Tag Manger and so forth. Using a PHP/HTML widget is most likely the easiest method or a relevant plugin. But personally I wouldn't tell them how... I'd charge them and do it myself ~ if they don't want them to pay then point them in the right direction to obtain such information i.e WP codex.

Comment: Thank you but I don't have interest to charge and install them myself for them, I charge them for widget and I want that widget to be installed on their site in as easy way as possible. Doing some further investigation I came out with idea to suggest them to install free Custom Script Integration module. Then they can add script through admin. This will be probably the easiest way for those who don't use Google Tag Manager and don't know programming.

Comment: @SimonHayter anything can be done in many ways, even when programming. If somebody told me it is possible to insert javascript code into wp site without Google Tag Manager and without installing extra module like you can do it with Magento it would be for sure best answer and not opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would install Google Tag Manager for them and then add misc scripts that way